# Disable Procdump

Tags: windows-7, dump, minidumps

I had an issue with a vendor product, then I had to run procdump to be able to narrow down the possible cause for this issue, now I need to disable it, is there any way to disable it without taking risks because it is on a critical server

Comment: can't post this as an answer. but check this http://forum.sysinternals.com/removing-procdump-as-aedebugger_topic29823.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `Procdump -u` to uninstall ProcDump. You see this when you run `procdump -h`:

> -u      Treat CPU usage relative to a single core (used with -c).
>           **As the only option, Uninstalls ProcDump as the postmortem debugger**.

Comment: Not available in older version. (At least version 6 and lower.)

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski yes, this was added in a newer version, but you should always use the most recent version to get all features.